# Cube map faster than 6 2D textures? - shadow mapping

Tags: shadow-mapping, cubemap

I've managed to implement shadow mapping to a scene. However, I had problems using a cube map so I eventually gave it up and used 6 2D texture maps instead. To make this work with 6 2D maps, during the rendering process I have to identify in which texture of the 6 each fragment belongs. I'm afraid this could be dropping my frames significantly.

I'm not gonna go into many details for now. I will upload the relevant code if necessary. My main concern is if this method makes my program slower.Will my fps increase using a cube map?

Comment: It probably will.

Comment: Yes; it's a single texture and there's no branching logic required in your pixel/fragment shader.  You should ask a new question about the problems you had with cube maps rather than editing or adding to this one, however.

Comment: There are no answers here yet, so I see no harm in editing the question to ask about the problems you've had implementing a cube map version instead.

Comment: I've already uploaded a question on the problems I've had. Actually, I have followed tutorials right on point and I don't know why it's not working. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/166342/i-cant-make-the-cube-map-to-use-shadow-mapping-or-it-seems-so I'll give it a shot again since it will be faster. I will soon delete this question, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use 6 individual textures as you can just use one big 2D strip with the dimensions x=shadowmap_width y= 6*shadowmap_height and then do 6 renderpasses adjusting the viewport to draw at the right place of the texture. (`glViewport` + `glScissor` in openGL).

That way you only have one texture sampler in your shaders and don't need 12 rebindings per render iteration. Also PCF using poisson disk sampling gets a lot easier since you have 2D texture coordinates.

This blog goes a bit deeper in how to do this and also points out potential issues and how you could solve them:
https://kosmonautblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/25/shadow-filtering-for-pointlights/